# Failed to install the requested application ios xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

So I had a fully working app, on which I was doing some updates, I was working on the last things, and testing on a real device, I run the app and test it, there was a UILabel text value I had to update, I did and ran the app again on the device to find an error stating "Unable to install iosApp" details below

```
Details

Unable to install "iosApp"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
--
Could not inspect the application package.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653103
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 282703;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000051)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a39b3b8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a3d9ae1 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000104f4fbac DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011a3d9822 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x00000001146d1999 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.294 + 3534
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000105082921 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010508454b __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201635dd _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff201647c7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2016a5fe _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2016b0cb _dispatch_lane_invoke + 375
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20174c5d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2030c499 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff2030b467 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.0.1 (Build 20B29)
Xcode 12.5.1 (18212) (Build 12E507)
Timestamp: 2021-07-25T19:23:09-07:00
```

Out of nowhere the app can't be installed any longer. I restarted xcode, rebooted the computer, rebooted the ipod, uninstalled the app, un-paired the ipod, re-paired the ipod, clean build, deleted cache and still same problem.

So I thought, maybe the ipod has a problem so I attempted to run this on an iphone and the same, in the simulator it acts a bit different, it then gives me this error details

```
Failed to install the requested application
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 22
Failure Reason: The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Recovery Suggestion: Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
User Info: {
    bundleURL = "file:///Users/tlacaelel-ramon-luis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iosApp-bgzddjaiahuysehfxtamviqbsuph/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.app/";
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.0.1 (Build 20B29)
Xcode 12.5.1 (18212) (Build 12E507)
Timestamp: 2021-07-25T19:30:10-07:00
```

So I went to check the build info.plist and the CFBundleIdentifier is there. I really don't know where to go from here as I can't test the app.

Has anyone any ideas of what can be causing this issue and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have a paid developer membership?

Comment: @matt yes, I have a paid account, does that make a difference? and by the way, it was working the whole day, it just decided to stop working out of nowhere.

Comment: @matt I was thinking about what you said, so I tried to install again from TestFlight and it works from there.

Comment: That's excellent! But we are no closer to understanding what's causing this issue.

Comment: I ended up creating a new project and moving all my controllers and configuration to it. It all ended "identical" if I can call it like that, but it seems that something got corrupted in the original file/s.